# I accepted an offer, then the company stopped responding. Do I keep chasing the offer?

Tags: job-offer

I was offered a position with a company. The offer letter was a little vague and unclear, so I sent back questions for clarification. The questions were clarified and explained, and I proudly accepted the offer.

The location was to be in another city with a mixture of office hours and working from home. The start date was determined, the location confirmed, the temporary housing agreement confirmed, it was all fine... Then all of a sudden, no communication.

Three days later the offer was rescinded. The email indicated the company was facing concurrent business issues to hire as planned but wanted to speak to me about an alternate plan. They told me to call to discuss. I have called, and sent emails, but this person that I previously had great communication with has stopped returning any calls or emails?

It's been over 30 days. I don't understand at all. How do I follow up? Or is this my cue to walk away? The position is still listed as an opening on the website.

Comment: It sounds like the company is in disarray. Perhaps your contact is no longer even there. I would consider this a risky company to move for even if they do step up with a fresh offer. I think you should walk away.

Comment: Did they countersign the offer you accepted?  Or more specifically, did you get to the point where you signed an actual employment contract?  If so, you _may_ be entitled to compensation for whatever your notice period should have been.  But that's about it.

Comment: It was all done over email. I have never experienced this before. The contact I was communicating with and drove to meet in the other city 2 1/2 hours away for my face to face interview was the CEO/President. I feel like I did something wrong. But I am continuing to seek other opportunity. Disappointed..

Comment: have you checked linked in? They might not be there anymore.

Comment: @PreetSangha - Important reference the company as `LinkedIn` considering they are not two seperate words in this case.

Comment: You can try submitting your resume again from scratch on their website and seeing what happens - if nothing else, it may get them to reach out to you...  Assuming it wasn't just an "email us your resume" form of contact.

Answer (score 14):

I'd interpret this sequence of events as "you are screwed". If it's any consolation to you, it could have been worse. Suppose that you had moved to the other city, and then they lowered the boom on you before you even got a chance to collect your first paycheck. If you haven't given notice on your current job yet, count yourself lucky.

I think that the question "Will I ever know why?" is irrelevant to you at this point. However, the question "Can I trust them and can I rely on anything they say going forward?" is very relevant, and I believe that the answer to this second question is obvious to you.